# C# network programming -- listening

Tags: c#, tcp, network-programming

I'm writing a client-server utility application. They communicate through `TcpClient`/`Stream` (client) and `TcpListener`/`Socket` (server). I send bytes back and forth between these two, then I come to the part where I have a problem; the client sends a signal to the server (say `StartCounting`). The client starts doing some stuff (say counts up from zero). The server does the same as soon as it receives the `StartCounting`. Now, while both sides are counting, each side may interrupt the counting (say by pressing return). When one side stops, it sends a message to the other side to stop. Here's some attempted code (for the client, but the only difference is how they read the byte array):

```
private void WaitForBye(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] responseBytes = new byte[1000]; 
    int k = stream.Read(responseBytes, 0, 1000);
    String response = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(responseBytes);
    response = response.Substring(0, k);

    String from, to, message;

    extractData(response, out message, out from, out to);

    Console.WriteLine(++counter);
    if (message == "BYE")
        isBye = true;
}

bTimer = new Timer();
bTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(WaitForBye);
bTimer.Interval = 1000;
bTimer.Enabled = true;

Console.WriteLine("Press return when finished.");
while (Console.ReadLine() != "" && !isBye) ;
```

How would I do that? Preferably without using threads and with a `Timer` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you could be counting and listening at the same time on the same thread, so my guess you'll have to look into threading for this one. C# 4.0 makes this kind of stuff a lot easier with Tasks.

A bit off topic, but why are you using sockets? Wouldn't WCF work jus fine here? It would save you a truckload of typing.

Good luck,

GJ

Comment: @offtopic: This is my first networking program and I want to work my way up from the lowest level.

Comment: Ok, going this route (bottom up) will provide with a lot of low level skills and understanding, that's for sure. It's not that scary if you want to understand it. WCF would enable you to get stuff into production a lot quicker and shield you from beginnner pitfalls. It does add some overhead that is true. But there are other communication frameworks that are better at that like MassTransit or Protocol Buffers.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with stream.peek to check if there is data to be read.
Otherwise your code would wait until there is data, and the counting would not work.
Remember that the message you read may not be complete, so don't use this approach for mission critical situations.

Using WCF would save typing, but would add to the payload of the communications.

Succes.

Comment: The `Stream` doesn't support a `Peek()` method. And what about the `Socket`?